# C++ Check if number is even or odd

Tags: c++

I have created program in C++ that checks if entered numbers are: even and positive,even and negative,odd and positive or odd and negative!
Is there any better solution to check this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    system("color f0");
    int n = 0, A[1337], B[1337];
    cout << "Enter number of array members: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter numbers : \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> A[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    B[i] = A[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    if (B[i] > 0 && B[i] % 2 == 0)
    cout << B[i] << " pp" << endl;
    if (B[i] > 0 && B[i] % 2 != 0)
    cout << B[i] << " pn" << endl;
    if (B[i] < 0 && B[i] % 2 != 0)
    cout << B[i] << " np" << endl;
    if (B[i] < 0 && B[i] % 2 == 0)
    cout << B[i] << " nn" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What's the reason for creating table `B`?

Comment: For starters, some variable names that actually means something normally helps.  That said this really sounds like a question for [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not Stack Overflow.

Comment: (a) you don't need both A and B, (b) you can just do two tests - one for oddness and one for negativeness.

Comment: by the way, your code ignores the possibility that someone may enter `0`

Comment: cout << A[i] << " " << (A[i] < 0? "n": "p") << (A[i]%2? "p":"n")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  system("color f0");
  int n = 0, A[1337];
  cout << "Enter number of array members: " << endl;
  cin >> n;
  //Make sure n is not bigger than your arrays
  if( n > 1337 )  n=1337;
  cout << "Enter numbers : \n";
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> A[i];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if( A[i] == 0 )
    {
      cout  << A[i] << " is 0" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
      cout << A[i] << " " << (A[i] < 0? "n": "p") << (A[i]%2? "p":"n"); 
    }

  }
  cout << endl;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```